# same paper was published in the same journal twice

Tags: journals

I just realized that the paper "Hitchin's connection and differential operators with values in the determinant bundle" by Xiaotao Suna and I-Hsun Tsai and was published twice in the Journal of Differential Geometry: in 67 (2004), no. 2, 335–376 and in 66 (2004), no. 2, 303–343. What is more, I found that each of these papers was reviewed individually in MathSciNet: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=262629&vfpref=html&r=1&mx-pid=2153081
and 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=262629&vfpref=html&r=2&mx-pid=2106127
It seems to me that they are the same paper. So I wonder if anyone knows the exact reason why the same paper was published in the same journal twice? Or in fact they are two different papers with different mathematical contents? Especially I would like to ask opinions from those who have read the paper.

Comment: Zentralblatt list these separately, but review only the second: Zbl 1080.14530 and Zbl 1120.14008

Comment: So surprised about a publisher mucking up?

Comment: Why does the number of pages differ by 1? (Do they start a paper at the top of a new page or at a random position on a page?).

Comment: Perhaps the second version had some additions/corrections? And somehow both got published (?).

Comment: I took a look: the two papers have the same content, but are not identical: one has the acknowledgement following the introduction, the other at the end; (this difference is also responsible for the different page length noted by @WłodzimierzHolsztyński ); so it seems the publisher was confused about whether this paper had already been copy-edited, and it went through the work flow twice; page proofs to the authors should have caught this duplication, but apparently did not.

Comment: Sun Xiaotao's page lists only the pp. 303-343 version: http://www.math.ac.cn/index_E/Personal_Web/Sunxiaotao_E.htm

Comment: Comment for others reading, not the OP: is it worth notifying MathReviews about this?

Comment: These things happen when publisher or editor messes up. Another example is "On the moduli spaces of polygons in the Euclidean plane" by Misha Kapovich and John Millson, published twice: Journal of Differential Geometry, Vol. 42 (1995) No. 1, p. 133-164 and again in No. 2, 430-464 of the same volume. I think, the first published version (in No. 1) did not include pictures.